# onscroll only fires once

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, onscroll

I have a javascript file I am using to align a single absolute div to always be inline with the horizontal scroll position.

I can't figure out what's not working with my code - onscroll seems to fire once and then never fire again in both internet explorer and firefox.

Anyone have any ideas? I've been looking this up for a bit and I can't figured out the error. (I have tried both onscroll += and onscroll =, neither work). That 39 offset is just to make sure the script fired until I get it to work.

```js
window.onload=scrollSet;

function scrollSet(){
 window.onscroll += KeepLeftAtScroll();
}


function KeepLeftAtScroll(){
 var ele=document.getElementById("topAboveMenuMargin");
 if (ele != null){
  ele.style.left = 39+ document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
 }
  
}
```

Comment: Why your're overriding native `window.onscroll`? `KeepLeftAtScroll` doesn't even return anything.

Comment: I'm using it to fire code that repositions a div every time the window is scrolled.

Comment: No, you're overriding the `window.onscroll` with `NaN`, which doesn't fire anything ; ). `onscroll` is supposed to be a function. Probably `window.onscroll = KeepLeftAtScroll;` does what you want.

Comment: As specified, I tried += and =, but I didn't know += overwrote. Thanks, I'll remember that. With = KeepLeftAtScroll, it still fires only once.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have only `KeepLeftAtScroll`, _not_ `KeepLeftAtScroll()`?

Comment: I don't get where this would matter, unless you mean did I have "function KeepLeftAtScroll{}"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Apparently javascript does not like seperating assignement and declaration, as

```js
window.onscroll = function KeepLeftAtScroll(){
 var ele=document.getElementById("topAboveMenuMargin");
 if (ele != null)
 {
  ele.style.left = window.pageXOffset;
 }
}
```

works and does what I want it to. It didn't seem to like "window.onscroll = KLAS()" but was ok with "window.onscroll = function KLAS(){}". I originally did the onload portion since I wasn't originally checking for null on my element and did it that way to get around that issue.

Either way, it seems solved. Thanks for all the help all.

Comment: Hmmm... This fixes the issue. Though `window.onscroll = KeepLeftAtScroll;` would also have done the job. You know there's a difference between function call and function reference?

Comment: Yes. I was having a ton of weird issues that evening, and for some reason window.onscroll = KLAT; did not work until I combined the declaration and assignment. I don't know what is up, but I tried checking it again and 

"window.onscroll = KeepLeftAtSroll; 
function KeepLeftAtScroll(){ -code-
}"

fails.